# how to solve this stray issue

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I'm using atollic to program stm32, but atollic does not accept hex numbers when I write in a form `0xXXXXXXXX`.

```c
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
void gpioab_config(void) {
    RCC->AHB1ENR=0x00000000; //ahb1 channel reset
    RCC->AHB1ENR=0x00000003; //AHB1 ENABLED FOR PORT A AND PORT B
    GPIOA->MODER =0x0C000000; //A PORT INPUT
    GPIOA->OTYPER= 0x00000000; //input port push pull
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR=0x0000003C; //pa1 and pa2 speed set to very high
    GPIOA->PUPDR=0x00000028; // pa1 and pa2 has been set to pull down

    GPIOB->MODER = 0x‭55000000‬; // b ports pb12 pb13 pb14 and pb15 pins are selected as output
    GPIOB->OTYPER = 0x00000000; //OUTPUT PORTS PUSH PULL
    GPIOB->OSPEEDR = 0x‭FF000000‬; //pb12 pb13 pb14 and pb15 speed set to very high
    GPIOB->PUPDR = 0x00000000; //pb12 pb13 pb14 and pb15 are no pull-Up_down

}


int main(void)
{


  while (1)
  {

  }
}
```

The error that atollic is showing is this:

[image]

How can I solve this?

atollic does not recognize hex numbers like `0xff0000`, `0x550000`, ...

Comment: always saying invalid suffix x...

Comment: Even SO highlighter shows that you use non Latin `x`. Switch your keyboard layout and retype.

Comment: The `x` is fine, my hex editor shows a `LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE` after the `x`.

Comment: @OnurYağcı the compiler is not complaining about *all* of the hex numbers, only the later ones. The ```stray '\200'``` errors are the likely cause. ```\200``` is octal, in hex that is `80`.  Meaning there is a stray byte `0x80` in your source file that shouldn't be in there. You need to fix your file. As [@DevSolar mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77852635/65863), your code actually contains some hidden Unicode controls characters in it. Assuming your source file is encoded in UTF-8, Unicode U+202C would be bytes `0xE2 0x80 0xAC` and U+202D would be bytes `0xE2 0x80 0xAD`.

Answer (score 4):

The two offending lines contain Unicode control characters U+202D (left-to-right override) after the `0x` and U+202C (pop directional formatting) in front of the `;` (most likely from a copy-paste of those values from a website).

[image: 'vim' screenshot]

This makes the two hex literals... not hex literals at all, which the compiler complains about. Those control characters have no business being in C++ source.

Make sure to set up your editor so that it will make you aware of such characters in some way, or use a source checker that will highlight non-standard characters. Personally, I have a little tool that will warn me if my source contains tabs (using spaces for indentation), non-ASCII-7 characters, or trailing spaces.

Comment: İ wrote <202d> and <202c> at the places here but nothing changed atollic is still complaining

Comment: @OnurYağcı You missed the point. This is your source code from the question, copy&pasted into my editor, which shows the non-printing control characters *already existing in your source* as four-digit hex codes, enclosed in <> and in red. These control characters have no business being in source code. You need to eliminate those control characters, completely. Delete and re-type the hexadecimal constant.